# Error when querying Microsoft Graph API Shifts: "MS-APP-ACTS-AS header needs to be set for application context requests"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

We are trying to query shifts in the Microsoft Graph API using a C# app, now that StaffHub got deprecated , in the past we were getting an Unknown Error which looked like a permissions issue.

In the docs I noticed permissions for `Schedule.ReadAll` and `Schedule.ReadWriteAll` so I added them to the application permissions in our App Registration in Azure.

Now when we send the request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{teamid}/schedule` we get this error:

```
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: Forbidden Message: {"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"MS-APP-ACTS-AS header needs to be set for application context requests.","details":[],"innererror":{"code":"MissingUserIdHeaderInAppContext"}}}
```

The documentation says the [Schedule permissions are in private preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schedule-list-shifts?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http), are these required for querying a schedule & shifts, and if so, is it possible to request access to the private preview?

Answer (score 3):

I'm in the same situation. It's possible to request private preview access (we have), but I'm guessing that it's primarily granted to Microsoft partners or at least have a connection at Microsoft.

The workaround for me has been [getting access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph%2Fapi%2Fbeta&view=graph-rest-beta). It does however require the user to enter username and password in order to get an access token, so it might not be a perfect solution for you. But it works. You need to add (and, I believe, grant admin consent for) delegated permissions for this to work, either `Group.Read.All` or `Group.ReadWrite.All`.

**Edit:**
I've got it working now. We have private preview access, so I'm not sure this will help you unless you do too, but as I understand it will be available eventually. Given your question, I presume you already have an access token.

[image: Add MS-APP-ACT-AS as a header with the user ID of the user you want the Graph client to act as.]

Add MS-APP-ACT-AS as a header with the user ID of the user you want the Graph client to act as.

If you're using the Graph SDK for .NET Core you can just add a header to the authentication provider:

```
public IAuthenticationProvider GetAuthenticationProviderForActingAsUser(string userId, string accessToken)
{
    return new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
        requestMessage =>
        {
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

            // Get event times in the current time zone.
            requestMessage.Headers.Add("Prefer", "outlook.timezone=\"" + TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id + "\"");
            requestMessage.Headers.Add("MS-APP-ACTS-AS", userId);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });
}
```

Then you call the graph service client:

```
var authenticationProvider = GetAuthenticationProviderForActingAsUser(userId, accessToken);    
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
```

You should then be able to fetch the shifts:

```
var shifts = await graphClient.Teams[teamId].Schedule.Shifts
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(shift);
```

Comment: This worked for me using Application permissions, via a token generated via the client_credentials authorisation flow (i.e. non-interactive), and we _don't_ have private preview access.

Just a note that the header is MS-APP-ACT**S**-AS (which is correct in your code sample and PostMan screenshot, but you've also listed MS-APP-ACT-AS in your text). Naturally that was the bit that I pasted!

Comment: I can confirm that you can just add any users ID to pass this error. No need to change anything else.